# Solution verification/clarification involving null space and row space for a set of planes

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering if someone could verify my solution/work for this question alongside a few other clarifications I had.

> a) Write the row space and the null space of the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\\ \end{bmatrix}$$as a span of vectors.

After row reduction, I get:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\\ \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

The basis of the row space just $\text{span}\{(1,0,-1),(0,1,2)\}$ and the null space is $\text{span}\{(1,-2,1) \}$.

> b) Describe the space of solutions to the equations
> \begin{cases} 
>       x_1+2x_2+3x_2=0 \\
>       4x_1+5x_2+6x_3=0 \\
>       7x_1+8x_2+9x_3=0 
>    \end{cases}

This is the same as the null space from part a, so it's just $\text{span}\{(1,-2,1) \}$.

> c) Compare your answers from part (a) and (b). What do you observe and why?

The solution space for the given system is the same as the null space. This makes sense since the Null space is just the solution to the system $Ax=0$ and the coefficients of the given system is the same as the entries in the matrix.

> d) Each equation in part (b) gives a plane. Describe the intersection of the 3 planes from part (b).

I'm not really sure how to describe this aside from the fact it's a scalar multiple of the null space of the the solution set.

> e) Describe the span of the normal vectors of the 3 planes from the equations in part (b). Describe how it relates to part (a). What is the geometry of this span? How is it related to the intersection of the 3 planes from part (d)? Why?

I'm not 100% sure about this part. Would would I describe the span of the normal vectors? I know the normal vectors are $\{1,2,3\}$,$\{4,5,6\}$,$\{7,8,9\}$ but I am not sure what the span of the normal vectors are supposed to exactly describe.

The span would be something like $k_1\{1,2,3\}+k_2\{4,5,6\}+k_3\{7,8,9\}=(a,b,c)$ for some arbritary vector $\vec{v}=(a,b,c).$

If the mean the geometry of the null space, then that's a line but again, because I am not sure what the span of the normal vectors should describe, I can't think of what geometry I should get.

Similarly, I can't see how this is related to part d. Would it not just be the same set of vectors from part d?

Comment: For d: you've shown that the solution of the equations correspond to the null space consisting of exactly one element. This geometrically means that the three planes are concurrent and the line of intersection is the line: $(x,y,z)=(t,-2t,t)$ passing through the origin (this line corresponds to the null space)

Comment: For part e: the span of the normal vectors correspond to the row space of the matrix in part a. As the rank of the matrix is 2, it corresponds to the plane generated by the vectors (1,0,-1) and (0,1,2) (passing through the origin). I.e. $x-2y+z=0$ whose normal is the straight line mentioned in part d.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure as to "Why" this happens but I believe that it's a consequence of the Rank-nullity dimension theorem (it would be great if someone else could verify this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers to a, b, c are fine.
For d, the three planes all intersect in a line, like pages of an open book.
For e, the span of the normal vectors is a plane--in particular, the plane perpendicular to the three planes represented by the equations.  The normal vectors span 2 dimensions, and they are orthogonal to the line of intersection, so their span is also orthogonal.